# Position of tf.global_variables_initializer()

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am beginner in deep learning and stuck to this problem .

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.utils import  shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#define the one hot encode function
def one_hot_encode(labels):
  n_labels = len(labels)
  n_unique_labels = len(np.unique(labels))
  one_hot_encode = np.zeros((n_labels,n_unique_labels))
  one_hot_encode[np.arange(n_labels), labels] = 1
  return one_hot_encode

#Read the sonar dataset
df = pd.read_csv('sonar.csv')
print(len(df.columns))
X = df[df.columns[0:60]].values
y=df[df.columns[60]]
#encode the dependent variable containing categorical values
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
y = encoder.transform(y)
Y = one_hot_encode(y)

#Transform the data in training and testing
X,Y = shuffle(X,Y,random_state=1)
train_x,test_x,train_y,test_y = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.20,       random_state=42)


#define and initialize the variables to work with the tensors
learning_rate = 0.1
training_epochs = 1000

 #Array to store cost obtained in each epoch
 cost_history = np.empty(shape=[1],dtype=float)

 n_dim = X.shape[1]
 n_class = 2

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,n_dim])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_dim,n_class]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_class]))

#initialize all variables.


#define the cost function
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,n_class])
y = tf.matmul(x, W)+ b
 init = tf.global_variables_initializer()#wrong position
cost_function =       tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y,labels=y_))

training_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost_function)
 init = tf.global_variables_initializer()#correct position
 #initialize the session

 sess = tf.Session()

  sess.run(init)
  mse_history = []

  #calculate the cost for each epoch
 for epoch in range(training_epochs):
sess.run(training_step,feed_dict={x:train_x,y_:train_y})
cost = sess.run(cost_function,feed_dict={x: train_x,y_: train_y})
cost_history = np.append(cost_history,cost)
print('epoch : ', epoch,  ' - ', 'cost: ', cost)

 pred_y = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: test_x})
 print(pred_y) 
#Calculate Accuracy
 correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred_y,1), tf.argmax(test_y,1))
 accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
 print(sess.run(accuracy))
 sess.close()
```

In the above code if I am using init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
above **AdamOptimizer** then it is giving error but if I am using it after 
**AdamOptimizer** then it is working fine. What is the reason?
Although it is working fine with **GradientDescentOptimizer** at both position.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [documentation](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/global_variables_initializer) the `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()` is the same as `init = tf.variables_initializer(tf.global_variables())`

The [`tf.train.AdamOptimizer`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/train/adamoptimizer) requires some internal variables (statistics of mean etc ) initialized

```
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'x/Adam:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32_ref>    # 1st moment vector
<tf.Variable 'x/Adam_1:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32_ref>  # 2nd moment vector
```

The [documentation](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/train/adamoptimizer) tells you how the updates are applied.

Instead, the vanilla gradient descent optimizer [`tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/train/gradientdescentoptimizer) does not depend on *any* variables. There is the difference.
Now, before the [`tf.train.AdamOptimizer`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/train/adamoptimizer) can use its variables, these variables need to be initialized at some point.

To create an operation `init` which initializes all needed variables, this op `init` needs to know which variable is required to run the program. Hence, it needs to be placed *after* [`tf.train.AdamOptimizer`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/train/adamoptimizer).

If you would place the `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()` *before* the [`tf.train.AdamOptimizer`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/train/adamoptimizer) like

```
init_op = tf.variables_initializer(tf.global_variables())
optimize_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cost_function)
```

you will get

```
Attempting to use uninitialized value beta1_power
```

which tells you, that [`tf.train.AdamOptimizer`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/train/adamoptimizer) tries to access `<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>`, which has been not initialized.

So

```
# ...
... = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cost_function)
# ...
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

is the only correct way. You can check, which variables could be initialized by placing

```
for variable in tf.global_variables():
    print(variable)
```

in the source code.

Consider the example of minimizing a quadratic form `0.5x'Ax + bx + c`. In TensorFlow this would be

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(2, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="x")
# we already make clear, that we are not going to optimize these variables
b = tf.constant([[5], [6]], dtype=tf.float32, name="b")
A = tf.constant([[9, 2], [2, 10]], dtype=tf.float32, name="A")

cost_function = 0.5 * tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x), A), x) - tf.matmul(tf.transpose(b), x) + 42

for variable in tf.global_variables():
    print('before ADAM: global_variables_initializer would init {}'.format(variable))

optimize_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cost_function)

for variable in tf.global_variables():
    print('after ADAM: global_variables_initializer would init
```

{}'.format(variable))

```
init_op = tf.variables_initializer(tf.global_variables())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)

    for i in range(5):
        loss, _ = sess.run([cost_function, optimize_op])
        print(loss)
```

The output is

```
before ADAM global_variables_initializer would init <tf.Variable 'x:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32_ref>
after ADAM global_variables_initializer would init <tf.Variable 'x:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32_ref>
after ADAM global_variables_initializer would init <tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
after ADAM global_variables_initializer would init <tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
after ADAM global_variables_initializer would init <tf.Variable 'x/Adam:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32_ref>
after ADAM global_variables_initializer would init <tf.Variable 'x/Adam_1:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32_ref>
```

So `tf.global_variables_initializer()` does not see the needed variables of ADAM, when placing `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()` before the ADAM definition `tf.train.AdamOptimizer`. When using the GradientDescentOptimizer the values are

```
before ADAM global_variables_initializer would init <tf.Variable 'x:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32_ref>
after ADAM global_variables_initializer would init <tf.Variable 'x:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32_ref>
```

So nothing changed before and after the optimizer.

Comment: but still some how giving error if I define init above AdamOptimizer. u can check if u want

Comment: There is a difference. Please have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()` *will only initialize the variables that are declared **before** it*.

For example, consider the following code:

```
variable_1 = tf.get_variable("v_1",[5,5],tf.float32,initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
variable_2 = tf.get_variable("v_2",[5,5],tf.float32,initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
```

the following code will print numbers (5x5, all zero) in `variable_1`:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init) 
    print(sess.run(variable_1))
```

However, the following code will produce an "Attempting to use uninitialized value" error:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init) 
    print(sess.run(variable_2))
```

To conclude, in most cases, just put `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()` after  all your other variables.